# How to change angular material option style?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I use the following code:

```
::ng-deep{
 .mat-select-panel{
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   position:absolute;
   top: 50px;
 }
}
```

I expected it to look **like** this:

[image]

but still, it's like this:

[image]

**And** It's ugly open **from** where it was **selected**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the latest  demo I shared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just add **panelClass** to select tag and style this class in **styles.scss**

`Html:`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select disableOptionCentering panelClass="dropDown-seasons-panel">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season.value">
         {{season.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

`styles.scss:`

```
.dropDown-seasons-panel {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  border: 1px solid gray !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: I want to show border radius in mat-select not in mat-options then how can I achieve that ?

Comment: you can set style for this class:  ".mat-select-panel"

Comment: There is a better solution not using !important. See this link, #3 "Overwriting AM styles in separate global styles — not scoped!" https://betterprogramming.pub/best-way-to-overwrite-angular-materials-styles-e38dc8b84962

Answer (score 3):

please confirm, Are you using CSS or SCSS. If you're using CSS it won't work. Change to SCSS.

**I have added the class using panelClass attribute in mat- select component. By using that class you can update the css**

If you're using SCSS please take my Demo here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhxdfy-piucvw

Also check your global style CSS file. Maybe that CSS can override this CSS.

Comment: I use scss. I exactly do like your Demo but nothing happens but if I add this code to style.scss everything is ok  but it's not the solution because it's changing all over my project

Comment: Can you add your html part? Then I can suggest.

Comment: <div class="seasons-part">
                    <span>نام فصل:</span>
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-select disableOptionCentering md-container-class="mySelect">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
                                {{food.viewValue}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>

Comment: also, I look at styles.scss , there is no class that overwrites.

Comment: I just updated the link(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhxdfy-piucvw) , I have added the class using panelClass attribute in mat- select component. By using that class you can update the css

Comment: tank you so much your demo doesn't work for me but I add panelClass to select tag and use this class in styles.css and everything work finally. really tank for your helping

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best practice, but you can try with adding them in style.csss with`!important`

.html

```
<mat-select id='myCustomDropdown' placeholder="Favorite food">
    <div class="custom-style">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
            {{ food.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
    </div>
</mat-select>
```

**style.css**

```
.custom-style .mat-option{
    color:red !important
 }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhxdfy-volp29?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.html)**

Comment: Ya, you can wrap it in a div with class `custom-panel` and then use the selector like `custom-panel.mat-select-panel`

Comment: could you please take a demo for me

Comment: wrap mat-form-field by a div by class="seasons-part" and in styles.scss =>  .seasons-part {
  .mat-select-panel {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    border: 1px solid gray !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 50px !important;
  }
} but it dosent work

Comment: Check the working demo, in style.css, I adeed `#myCustomDropdown .mat-select-placeholder{
    color:red !important
  }`

Comment: My select tag is ok but the option tag doesn't work

Comment: could you please take a demo for changing the style of options

Comment: Check the modified answer and demo. Add a div just above the `<mat-option>`

Comment: yes but not works for me. I think some of my classes were overwriting.